# Find records from one table which don't exist in another

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got the following two tables (in MySQL):

```
Phone_book
+----+------+--------------+
| id | name | phone_number |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | John | 111111111111 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 2  | Jane | 222222222222 |
+----+------+--------------+

Call
+----+------+--------------+
| id | date | phone_number |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | 0945 | 111111111111 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 2  | 0950 | 222222222222 |
+----+------+--------------+
| 3  | 1045 | 333333333333 |
+----+------+--------------+
```

How do I find out which calls were made by people whose `phone_number` is not in the `Phone_book`? The desired output would be:

```
Call
+----+------+--------------+
| id | date | phone_number |
+----+------+--------------+
| 3  | 1045 | 333333333333 |
+----+------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 581, accepted):

There's several different ways of doing this, with varying efficiency, depending on how good your query optimiser is, and the relative size of your two tables:

This is the shortest statement, and may be quickest if your phone book is very short:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    Call
WHERE   phone_number NOT IN (SELECT phone_number FROM Phone_book)
```

alternatively (thanks to [Alterlife](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36848/alterlife))

```
SELECT *
FROM   Call
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
   FROM   Phone_book
   WHERE  Phone_book.phone_number = Call.phone_number)
```

or (thanks to WOPR)

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Call
LEFT OUTER JOIN Phone_Book
  ON (Call.phone_number = Phone_book.phone_number)
  WHERE Phone_book.phone_number IS NULL
```

(ignoring that, as others have said, it's normally best to select just the columns you want, not '`*`')

Comment: avoid IN, use EXISTS - the hint is in the question title

Comment: The left outer join is probably quickest in the general case as it prevents repeated execution of the subquery.

Comment: Not to be picky, but the subquery on my suggestion returns <code>select 'x'</code> and not <code>select *</code>

Comment: yes - MySQL manual suggests that this is normal for an 'EXISTS' query

Comment: @Alnitak: In the second query you don't need `SELECT *` in the subquery. Instead, for instance, `SELECT 1`, should be pretty enough.

Comment: Re `SELECT 1` in above comment: AFAIK, `EXISTS( SELECT ..`, in modern DBs, optimizes to the same result, regardless of what you put after SELECT.  Smart enough to know that `EXISTS` doesn't use the contents of the row. Nevertheless, it doesn't hurt from a readability standpoint to make it obvious that you aren't using the contents :)

Comment: NOTE: `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (from WOPR) may return multiple rows per row of `Call`, if `Phone_Book` has multiple matching entries. Any time you have `1:N` relationship between the two tables, you may get multiple rows. In this case, may be preferable to use Alterlife's `NOT EXISTS` approach.

Answer (score 122):

```
SELECT Call.ID, Call.date, Call.phone_number 
FROM Call 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Phone_Book 
  ON (Call.phone_number=Phone_book.phone_number) 
  WHERE Phone_book.phone_number IS NULL
```

Should remove the subquery, allowing the query optimiser to work its magic.

Also, avoid "SELECT *" because it can break your code if someone alters the underlying tables or views (and it's inefficient).

Comment: This is generally the most efficient method as it does not perform multiple passes on the second table ... hope some people are reading the comemnts.

Comment: I would rather hope that people profile: unless you're a top SQL performance guru, telling in advance what will be the fastest is quite difficult (and depends on the DBMS engine you use).

Comment: Big O notation will easily tell you what you can expect to be fastest in this case.  It's orders of magnitude different.

Comment: See [Afterlife's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/367873/199364) and my comment there, if there is a `1:N` relationship between your two tables.  OR add `DISTINCT` as seen in [Vlado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14356484/199364)

Answer (score 31):

The code below would be a bit more efficient than the answers presented above when dealing with larger datasets.

```
SELECT *
FROM Call
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'x'
    FROM Phone_book
    WHERE Phone_book.phone_number = Call.phone_number
);
```

Comment: As always, it's worth profiling the performance of the queries against your target dataset to choose the one with the best performance. SQL optimisers are good enough these days that the performance results are often surprising.

Comment: An advantage of this approach (vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN by WOPR) is that it avoids returning multiple rows per row of `Call`, if there are multiple matching rows in `Phone_book`. That is, if there is a `1:N` relationship between your two tables.

Comment: I would START with this one - it directly represents the intent. If performance not good enough, make sure appropriate indexes exist. Only then, try the less-obvious `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, see if its performance is better.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Call.id 
FROM Call 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Phone_book USING (id) 
WHERE Phone_book.id IS NULL
```

This will return the extra id-s that are missing in your Phone_book table.

Answer (score 5):

I think

```
SELECT CALL.* FROM CALL LEFT JOIN Phone_book ON 
CALL.id = Phone_book.id WHERE Phone_book.name IS NULL
```

Comment: The `id` column in the `call` table is not the same value as the `id` column in the `Phone_book` table, so you can't join on these values.  See WOPR's answer for a similar approach.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT t1.ColumnID,
CASE 
    WHEN NOT EXISTS( SELECT t2.FieldText  
                     FROM Table t2 
                     WHERE t2.ColumnID = t1.ColumnID) 
    THEN t1.FieldText
    ELSE t2.FieldText
END FieldText       
FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2
```

Comment: This will return you data from one table if data is not present in another table for the same column

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```
select id from call
minus
select id from phone_number
```

Comment: Not sure this answers the question as is (although the MINUS) operator is a new addition. This ended up in the low quality queue - you might like to enhance this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, phone_number FROM Call a
WHERE a.phone_number NOT IN (SELECT b.phone_number FROM Phone_book b)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10501884)

Comment: @DennisKriechel updated query so that it's more specific to the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Don't forget to check your indexes!

If your tables are quite large you'll need to make sure the phone book has an index on the  `phone_number` field. With large tables the database will most likely choose to scan both tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Call
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT *
   FROM   Phone_book
   WHERE  Phone_book.phone_number = Call.phone_number)
```

You should create indexes both `Phone_Book` and `Call` containing the `phone_number`. If performance is becoming an issue try an lean index like this, with only the phone number:

The fewer fields the better since it will have to load it entirely. You'll need an index for both tables.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].Phone_Book ADD CONSTRAINT [IX_Unique_PhoneNumber] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    Phone_Number
)
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

If you look at the query plan it will look something like this and you can confirm your new index is actually being used. Note this is for SQL Server but should be similar for MySQL.

With the query I showed there's literally no other way for the database to produce a result other than scanning every record in both tables.

[image]