# Transact SQL WHERE CURSOR

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

i have this table

```
TableA  
uID   |   uData  
1     |   111  
2     |   222  
3     |   333  
4     |   444  
5     |   555  

Table B  
uID   |   uData2  
1     |   222  
2     |   444
```

what i want is to get only the data from TableA which not in the data from TableB

> **OUTPUT**:

```
uID   |   uData  
1     |   111  
3     |   333 
5     |   555
```

so far, i made this solution

```
DECLARE allData CURSOR FOR
SELECT uData
FROM         TableA;
OPEN allData;
FETCH NEXT FROM allData;

print @allData;

--WHILE @@allData = '222'
--  BEGIN
--      FETCH NEXT FROM allData;
--  END
CLOSE allData;
DEALLOCATE allData;
GO
```

and got this error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@allData".

is there any other way to do this without using while in sql or any other solution? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT *
    FROM TableA 
    WHERE uData NOT IN (
       SELECT uData2
       FROM TableB
    )
```

Comment: check this http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm

Answer (score 2):

Just use a left join and filter out the records where there is data from the second table:

```
select t1.uID, t1.uData
from TableA t1
left join TableB t2 on t2.uData2 = t1.uData
where t2.uData2 is null
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a cursor; just exclue values from TableB using the following method:

```sql
select tableA.* 
from   tableA 
where  tableA.uData not in (select TableB.uData2 from TableB)
```

Further, your syntax for the `CURSOR` is wrong.  Check out [this quick example](http://cgaskell.wordpress.com/2006/12/06/sql-tsql-cursor-syntax-a-quick-reference/) for proper `CURSOR` syntax for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.Uid = tableB.Uid
WHERE tableB.Uid IS NULL
```