# Mysql Join, Sum, Having, Group By. Cant figure it out

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, inner-join, having

I'm having an issue with mysql when doing a JOIN of two tables and filtering using HAVING for these two tables.

Assume my tables look like this:

**Products:**

```
id | Name
1  | Product 1
2  | Product 2
3  | Product 3
```

**Reviews:**

```
Name     | Product_id | score
Review 1 | 1          | 10000
```

My best guess was the following, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT "products".*, sum("reviews".score) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "reviews" ON "reviews"."empire_id" = "products"."id" GROUP BY products.id HAVING sum("reviews".score)=0;
```

And I would like to get **the products that have a score of 0**, meaning that they have not been reviewed. I feel like this should be easy, but I can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want products that show up in the "products" table but not the "reviews" table. Perhaps take a look at [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)?

Alternatively, replacing your INNER JOIN with a LEFT JOIN might work.

Comment: You helped me figure it out!

Thanks


SELECT products.id, products.name, sum("reviews".score)
FROM products
LEFT JOIN reviews ON reviews.product_id= products.id
GROUP BY products.id, products.name
HAVING SUM("reviews".SCORE) IS NULL;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, sum("reviews".score)
FROM products
LEFT JOIN reviews ON reviews.product_id = products.id
GROUP BY products.id, products.name
HAVING sum(reviews.score)=0;
```

"reviews"."empire_id" = "products"."id"

Should be "reviews"."product_id" = "products"."id"

Actually your group by should have all your field name from product

Comment: You SQL should get what u r asking for, just the join have some error

Comment: mmm, it didn't really work. It only works for the products that have reviews "attached" to them. But if I want to get the products that dont have anything attached to them (ie, there's no review that has that product's id in the product_id field, then it doesnt work...)