# Intersection of two (very) big tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have two tables: `all_users` and `vip_users`

`all_users` table has a list of all users (you don't say?) in my system and it currently has around 57k records, while `vip_users` table has around 37k records.

Primary key in both tables is an autoincrement `id` field. `all_users` table is big in terms of attribute count (around 20, one of them is `email`), while `vip_users` table has only (along with `id`) `email` attribute.

I wanted to query out the "nonVip" users by doing this (with help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another) here on SO):

```
SELECT all_users.id, all_users.email
FROM all_users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vip_users 
    ON (all_users.email=vip_users.email) 
WHERE vip_users.email IS NULL
```

And now, finally coming to the problem - I ran this query in phpmyadmin and even after 20 minutes I was forced to close it and restart httpd service as it was taking too long to complete, my server load jumped over 2 and the site (which also queries the database) became useless as it was just loading too slow. So, my question is - how do I make this query? Do I make some script and run it over night - not using phpmyadmin (is this maybe where the problem lies?), or do I need to use different SQL query?

Please help with your thoughts on this.

Comment: Does the tables have indexes? Try to index email field on both tables

Comment: Did yo intend to join on user id, rather than email? As written, you're joining on email address, then checking if it's null?

Comment: @jwismar id are auto incremental on both tables, they would'nt match

Comment: 37k and 57k are not really big.

Comment: @Nico: Post that as an answer. 101% the issue is the lack of indexes.

Comment: Why not just make a `boolean` or `tinyint` `user_is_vip` column into `all_users`? Why even create a `vip_users` table if it only holds user id and email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try indexing the fields email on both tables, that should speed up the query

```
CREATE INDEX useremail ON all_users(email)

CREATE INDEX vipemail ON vip_users(email)
```

Comment: oh, you were so right!, this now gives me the answer in quoting: "Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 21,714 total, Query took 0.0043 sec)"

Answer (score 0):

I think `NOT IN` is faster and used less resource than `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Can you try -

```
SELECT *
FROM all_users
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id 
                 FROM vip_users
                 WHERE email IS NULL);
```

Comment: In MySQL, you specifically do NOT want to use a subselect. A join is much faster.  EDIT- I just doublechecked, and this may no longer be true in MySQL >= version 6.0.

Comment: @jwismar: No, you are confusing the behaviour of `IN (SELECT ...)` - which is often slow - with the behaviour of `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` which rarely has any issues. Similar performance with `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` or `NOT EXISTS (subquery)`

Answer (score 0):

As written, you're not getting the results you're looking for. You're looking for vip_users rows where the email matches an email in users, and is also NULL.

Is there a reason you want vip_users to have a separate id from users? If you change the vip_users id field to a fk on the users id field, yo would then change your select to:

```
SELECT all_users.id, all_users.email
FROM all_users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN vip_users 
    ON (all_users.id=vip_users.id) 
WHERE vip_users.email IS NULL;
```

There's no reason this query should take any discernible about of time.  37k records is not a very big table....