# inner join with empty result from right table

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 2 tables, restaurants and orders, each restaurant can have many orders

```
restaurants table
id
name


orders table
id
restaurant_id
date
```

I need to find the restaurants that have no orders on some date range. In orders table I save the order dates like - each row represents one day. So, I need to make inner join, but with no results from the orders table. Say, I need to find restaurants that are free from `2013-08-09 to 2013-08-11` date range. How can I achieve this ? How to make a query, that will give the restaurants with no matching in the orders table - according to the date range ?

Actually I can do it saving all the dates in the orders table with status not_ordered, and make inner join with `not_ordered = true` condition, but in that case I will have to populate all the table with the dates, which is not a good thing in my case.

Thanks

Comment: look [here also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another), the similar problem, but without accent on `joins`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select r.*
from restaurant r
left join orders o on r.id = o.restaurant_id and o.date between '...' and '...'
where o.id is null;
```

Or you can do it using `not exists` as shown in other answers.

Comment: +1. This is the classic "anti-join" pattern: a LEFT JOIN to find matching rows (all restaurants along with matching orders", and then a WHERE clause to eliminate restaurants that had a matching rows in orders. This is usually more efficient than an equivalent query using a `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS` predicate.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use an inner join for this. You can do it with an outer join, or with `NOT EXISTS` and a sub-query.

Here's an example of the latter approach:

```
select r.id,r.name 
from restaurants r 
where not exists (
  select NULL
  from orders o 
  where o.restaurant_id = r.id 
  and o.date >= '2013-08-09'
  and o.date <= '2013-08-11'
);
```

Comment: +1. the correlated subquery has a reference to an expression from the outer query. this is how it is done, though we usually (not always) get better performance with an anti-join.

Comment: I use the anti-join more often myself, but I think it's useful to know both approaches.

Comment: I agree it's useful to know both approaches, which is why I upvoted your answer.  Sometimes the `NOT EXISTS` predicate is the more appropriate approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know mysql very well, but this should work as general SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM restaurants 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM order 
                 WHERE restaurant_id=id AND 
                       date BETWEEN '2013-08-09' AND '2013-08-11')
```

Comment: Is `id` in the subquery a reference to the `id` column in the `restaurant` table or the `order` table? Best practice dictates that column references be qualified with either a table name, or preferably, a table alias.