# List all products with no prices in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This query is for a niche price comparison website.

I have 2 tables, the first lists product details and the second lists all the prices associated with the product. A product can have one or many prices.

I am looking to list all the products that have no active prices for housekeeping purposes.

It is possible to have an entry in the price table where the price = zero, in which case Prod_price_active would be set to "0". If a product does have a price, then Prod_price_active would be set to "1"

**Table 1**

```
Prod_id
Prod_name
Prod_description
```

**Table 2**

```
Price_id
Prod_id
Prod_price
Prod_price_active
```

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136113/inner-join-with-empty-result-from-right-table/18136209#18136209

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest query to understand is:

```
select * from table1
where not exists (
    select * from table2
    where Prod_price_active = 1
    and Prod_id = table1.Prod_id)
```

This is the SQL version of the sentence "give me all products that don't have an active price"

Comment: Why the nested queries? It might be one solution but it's better to avoid them when possible.

Comment: +1 . . . for being the only correct answer.  It's not worth adding the same thing with a left outer join.

Comment: @ktm5124 see edits. a beginner would be able to understand this better. It will perform fine: If the query was over a transaction table with millions of rows, I wouldn't recommend this approach, but how many products can there be?

Comment: @Gordon, I think left join will perform better, as in my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136113/inner-join-with-empty-result-from-right-table/18136209#18136209

Comment: There will always be less than 500 products, with each product having on average 5 prices. This query will only ever be run when doing house keeping. Just out of interest, what is the more efficient way of performing this query?

Comment: @Simon . . . If you have an index on `table2(Prod_id, Prod_price_active)`, the then performance will be fine using either method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming every product is in the price table, you can do an `inner join`.

```
select a.Prod_id, a.Prod_name, a.Prod_description 
from PRODUCTS a inner join PRICES b 
on a.Prod_id = b.Prod_id 
where b.Prod_price_active=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a way to perform an [anti-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29):

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
                LEFT JOIN table2 USING(prod_id) 
                WHERE Prod_price IS NULL
                OR Prod_price_active = 0
```

This will keep only those rows from `table1` (the "product table") that don't have a corresponding entry on `table2` (the "price table") *or* those having `Prod_price_active` set to 0.