# How to return rows from left table not found in right table?

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have two tables with similar column names and I need to return records from the left table which are not found in the right table? I have a primary key(column) which will help me to compare both tables. Which join is preferred?

Comment: Seems quite a basic query... What have you tried so far ?

Comment: @Siva Left outer join returns all the rows from the left table even if there are no matching records in the right table. I need to return matching records that are found in left table but not found in the right table.

Comment: Are you still having issues with your query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server?rq=1 Highly recommend checking out this answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows with no matching entry in another table?](/q/4076098/90527)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you are asking for T-SQL then lets look at fundamentals first. There are three types of joins here each with its own set of logical processing phases as:

1. A `cross join` is simplest of all. It implements only one logical query processing phase, a `Cartesian Product`. This phase operates on the two tables provided as inputs to the join and produces a Cartesian product of the two. That is, each row from one input is matched with all rows from the other. So if you have m rows in one table and n rows in the other, you get m×n rows in the result.
2. Then are `Inner joins` : They apply two logical query processing phases: `A Cartesian product` between the two input tables as in a cross join, and then it `filters` rows based on a predicate that you specify in `ON` clause (also known as `Join condition`).
3. Next comes the third type of joins, `Outer Joins`:

   In an `outer join`, you mark a table as a `preserved` table by using the keywords `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, or `FULL OUTER JOIN` between the table names. The `OUTER` keyword is `optional`. The `LEFT` keyword means that the rows of the `left table` are preserved; the `RIGHT` keyword means that the rows in the `right table` are preserved; and the `FULL` keyword means that the rows in `both` the `left` and `right` tables are preserved.

   The third logical query processing phase of an `outer join` identifies the rows from the preserved table that did not find matches in the other table based on the `ON` predicate. This phase adds those rows to the result table produced by the first two phases of the join, and uses `NULL` marks as placeholders for the attributes from the nonpreserved side of the join in those outer rows.

Now if we look at the question: To return records from the left table which are not found in the right table use `Left outer join` and filter out the rows with `NULL` values for the attributes from the right side of the join.

Answer (score 114):

Try This

```
SELECT f.*
FROM first_table f LEFT JOIN second_table s ON f.key=s.key
WHERE s.key is NULL
```

For more please read this article : [Joins in Sql Server](https://medium.com/@CodAffection/complete-guide-on-joins-in-sql-server-726a76a1274d)

[image]

Comment: key is IS NULL not = NULL

Comment: @HaydenThring s.key = NULL means no matching row found in second table,so condition is true i think

Comment: sorry i meant "the key to getting this to work is" not to be confused with use of "key" as a variable in this answer

Comment: In the left join, A&B will the output as per the diagram. Can you clarify me if adding "WHERE s.key is NULL" at the end of statement will remove the results in the B?

Comment: NOT EXISTS might be better:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121034/best-practice-between-using-left-join-or-not-exists

Answer (score 12):

I also like to use NOT EXISTS. When it comes to performance if index correctly it should perform the same as a LEFT JOIN or better. Plus its easier to read.

```
SELECT Column1
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Column1
                   FROM Tableb b
                   WHERE a.Column1 = b.Column1
                 )
```

Answer (score 2):

This page gives a decent breakdown of the different join types, as well as venn diagram visualizations to help... well... visualize the difference in the joins.

As the comments said this is a quite basic query from the sounds of it, so you should try to understand the differences between the joins and what they actually mean.

Check out http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

You're looking for a query such as:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (test int)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (test int)

INSERT INTO @table1
(
    test
)
SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 2

INSERT INTO @table2
(
    test
)
SELECT 1
UNION ALL SELECT 3

-- Here's the important part
SELECT  a.*
FROM    @table1 a
LEFT    join @table2 b on a.test = b.test -- this will return all rows from a
WHERE   b.test IS null -- this then excludes that which exist in both a and b

-- Returned results:

2
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't add anything but a code example to the other two answers: however, I find it can be useful to see it in action (the other answers, in my opinion, are better because they explain it).

```
DECLARE @testLeft TABLE (ID INT, SomeValue VARCHAR(1))
DECLARE @testRight TABLE (ID INT, SomeOtherValue VARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @testLeft (ID, SomeValue) VALUES (1, 'A')
INSERT INTO @testLeft (ID, SomeValue) VALUES (2, 'B')
INSERT INTO @testLeft (ID, SomeValue) VALUES (3, 'C')


INSERT INTO @testRight (ID, SomeOtherValue) VALUES (1, 'X')
INSERT INTO @testRight (ID, SomeOtherValue) VALUES (3, 'Z')

SELECT l.*
FROM 
    @testLeft l
     LEFT JOIN 
    @testRight r ON 
        l.ID = r.ID
WHERE r.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: if you are using Mysql replace the last line

 WHERE r.ID IS NULL 
with 
 WHERE ISNULL(r.ID)

Answer (score 2):

select * from left table where key field not in (select key field from right table)

Comment: Can you post an explanation for why your code works? also use the formatting tools to better format your answer.

Comment: This is one of the correct ways to solve the question. But, its performance is not good if we work with 10k, 20k records

Answer (score 0):

I also like to use NOT IN. When it comes to performance if index correctly it should perform the same as a LEFT JOIN or better. Plus its easier to read.

```
SELECT Column1
FROM TableA a
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT Column2
                   FROM Tableb b
                   WHERE a.Column1 = b.Column2
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example from real life work, I was asked to supply a list of users that bought from our site in the last 6 months but not in the last 3 months.

For me, the most understandable way I can think of is like so:

```
--Users that bought from us 6 months ago and between 3 months ago.
DECLARE @6To3MonthsUsers table (UserID int,OrderDate datetime)
INSERT @6To3MonthsUsers
    select u.ID,opd.OrderDate
        from OrdersPaid opd
        inner join Orders o
        on opd.OrderID = o.ID
        inner join Users u
        on o.BuyerID = u.ID
        where 1=1 
        and opd.OrderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(m,-6,GETDATE()) and DATEADD(m,-3,GETDATE())

--Users that bought from us in the last 3 months
DECLARE @Last3MonthsUsers table (UserID int,OrderDate datetime)
INSERT @Last3MonthsUsers
    select u.ID,opd.OrderDate
        from OrdersPaid opd
        inner join Orders o
        on opd.OrderID = o.ID
        inner join Users u
        on o.BuyerID = u.ID
        where 1=1 
        and opd.OrderDate BETWEEN DATEADD(m,-3,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Now, with these 2 tables in my hands I need to get only the users from the table **@6To3MonthsUsers** that are not in **@Last3MonthsUsers** table.

There are 2 simple ways to achieve that:

1. Using Left Join:

   ```
   select distinct a.UserID
   from @6To3MonthsUsers a
   left join @Last3MonthsUsers b
   on a.UserID = b.UserID
   where b.UserID is null
   ```
2. Not in:

   ```
   select distinct a.UserID
   from @6To3MonthsUsers a
   where a.UserID not in (select b.UserID from @Last3MonthsUsers b)
   ```

Both ways will get me the same result, I personally prefer the second way because it's more readable.