# SQL to retrieve only if there is no FK reference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables as shown below they have a one to many relationship. match table (one) message_log table (many) using match_id as a FK

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

I'm trying to write an sql statement that would return all the match_ids that do not exist in the message_log table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: Please post table definitions and sample data as formatted ***text***, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you all the match_ids, in the match table, that do not exist in the message_log table:

```
SELECT 
m.match_id
FROM match m
WHERE 
m.match_id NOT IN
(
    SELECT
    ml.match_id 
    FROM message_log ml
)
```

Example SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bacb5/1/0

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT m.match_id 
  FROM "match" m LEFT OUTER JOIN "message_id" g ON m.match_id = g.match_id
 WHERE g.match_id IS NULL
```

Try different solutions, as the optimizer will sometimes do interesting things.