# Query Builder and find records from one table which don't exist in another using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, query-builder

I am using Laravel 5 and its Query Builder to retrieve data from database.
I want to take following output.

I want to take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another) question thinks using Query Builder

Now I try this code, but not successfully:

```
$all_members = CommiteeMember::join('members', 'commiteeMembers.memberId', '<>', 'members.id')
->where('commiteeId', $commitee->id)->get();
```

Comment: In what way did this code not succeed? What are you trying to do?

Comment: this code out put is not correct. it give all details. :-( but i want to do above link things.

Comment: @uma you will have to use either left or right join as per your table requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve.

But from your title looks like what you need is left join.

```
 $all_members = CommiteeMember::leftJoin('members', 'commiteeMembers.memberId', '<>', 'members.id')
->where('commiteeId', $commitee->id)->get();
```

Comment: Thank you.....! @sstarlight i try this. really i want build quarry to take result like this question. deference ,I use  laravel quary builder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another