# Database query on 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

[image]

I have 2 tables (tag_details and movie_tags) and I want to query those tag_details_id (tag_details) that are NOT part of the movie_tags table. How can I easily get this done?

Comment: There's a RIGHT JOIN in there somewhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily with a subquery.

```
Select * from tag_details 
   where tag_details_id not in 
                        (Select tag_details_id from movie_tags)
```

Comment: thks.. and how does the query change if I want to add to the WHERE clause where (in the movie_tags table) movie_id should be a specific value.. something like Where movie_tags.movie_id = '10' AND tag_details_id not in (Select tag_details_id from movie_tags)

Comment: What happens when you try it.  You need to do some research into sql statements, what you are asking is very basic, try a tutorial http://sqlzoo.net/

Answer (score 2):

Learn how to use [outer joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)!

```
Select * 
from tag_Details TD
LEFT JOIN movie_tags MT
  on TD.Tag_Details_ID = MT.Tag_Details_ID
WHERE MT.Tag_Details_Id is null
```

or as a right join if you change table order...

```
Select * 
from movie_tags MT
RIGHT JOIN tag_Details TD
  on TD.Tag_Details_ID = MT.Tag_Details_ID
WHERE MT.Tag_Details_Id is null
```

This says return all tag_details and related records in movie tags, but only if the movie tag is NULL (which results from missing data, thus what you're after)

Answer (score 1):

You have to select all `tag_details_Id` that are not in the `movie_tags` table.

This can be achieved with a subquery as follows:

```
select * 
from tag_details 
where tag_details_Id not in (select tag_details_Id from movie_tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT tag_details_id
FROM tag_details
MINUS
SELECT tag_details_id
FROM movie_tags;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are generally considered to be of low quality