# Checking if data has entries at another table

Tags: mysql

So I have 2 tables, with the following columns:

-Sellers (name, userid)

-Products (name, id, sellerid)

So, the userid from Seller table is the same as the sellerid from Products table.

Now I need to create a query to return which are the sellers that have no product created at the products table.

Can you help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 0):

To get all Sellers who have no product, we get all id in the product table, and use 'NOT IN'

```
Select ('name', 'userid') from Sellers Where 'userid' NOT IN (Select 'sellerid' from Products)
```