# SQL Check one list against Another

Tags: sql, list, comparison

I'd appreciate any pointers on how in SQL to check whether elements in one list also appear in another.

```
List A = Live Customers in April
List B = Live Customers in May
```

How can I check which Customers in List A also appear in List B ? to identify those Customers which have been lost

```
i.e. Customers in A but not in B.
```

Thank you for your help. Gav

Comment: There are a number of ways to handle this problem, but you need to show us some table structure if you want an actionable answer.

Comment: also please mention RDBMS you are using like SQLServer,Oracle,mysql,postgre..

Comment: The SQL Standard defines `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` [Set operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)), but not all DBMS implement them. But as stated, it depends what database vendor and version you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 8):

Different ways to pull the results

```
SELECT customer
FROM ListA a 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ListB b WHERE a.customer=b.customer)
```

OR

```
SELECT a.customer
FROM ListA a 
  LEFT JOIN ListB b ON a.customer=b.customer
WHERE b.customer is null
```

OR

```
SELECT customer
FROM ListA

except

SELECT customer
FROM ListB
```

OR

```
SELECT customer
FROM ListA 
WHERE customer NOT IN (SELECT customer FROM ListB )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the `not in` clause

example

```
select * 
from mytable 
where id not in (select id from table2)
```

this will return results that are not in another table. quick and simple

Comment: Check this answer on impact of not in :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists