# Oracle sql. Compare two tables to find missing data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables:

Operator (id, name, product_id)
Product (id)

Operator table contains this data:

```
| 1 | Op1 | Pr1 |  
| 2 | Op2 | Pr2 |
```

Product table:

```
|    Pr1   |  
|    Pr2   |  
|    Pr3   |
```

And what i need is to show the products that Op1 does NOT have, and 
products that Op2 does NOT have:

```
| Op1 | Pr2 |  
| Op1 | Pr3 |  
| Op2 | Pr1 |  
| Op2 | Pr3 |
```

Could you please advise an efficient way of solving this task. 
I have 1 solution with building cross join, but i think there should be a right and easier way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `minus`:

**<sup>[demo](http://rextester.com/PKU19648)</sup>**

```
select o.name op_name, p.name pr_name from operator o cross join product p
minus 
select name, product_id from operator
```

Comment: Thanks for an elegant and simple solution. And for demo link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your data model.  You seem to have a column called `operator.name` that is supposed to match `product.id`.  Let me assume the data format is actually reasonable.  You should really have three tables:

- `Operators` -- with one row per "operator_id"
- `Products` -- with one row per "product_id"
- `OperatorProducts`  -- a junction table between the two

You can do this in two steps.  Start by creating all combinations of operator and product (`cross join`).  Then weed out the ones that are present (`left join`):

```
select o.operator_id, p.product_id
from (select distinct id as operator_id from operator) o cross join
     product p left join
     operator op
     on op.id = o.operator_id and op.product_id = p.product_id
where p.product_id is null;
```

If you need the names, you can join them in.

Comment: Regarding the table structure i wanted to have as simple model in the question as possible, but i made a typo in product table, it contains an id. Just lets assume that id is the product name.
And regarding your answer. Thank you for suggestion, i thought about something similar using cross join, but just was not sure that it's the best solution..

Answer (score 0):

A cross join is what is needed here.

```
select o.name, p.id from product p
cross join operator o
where 
  o.product_id != p.id
```