# Finding all the missing parts grouped by model

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains all the parts a particular car Model requires:

```
CarBuild
-id
-model
-partId
```

So to get all the parts for a model you would do:

```
select * from CarBuild where model=f150
```

The CarProgress has the cars currently being manufactured and what parts have been installed.

```
CarProgress
-model
-partId
```

How can i query all the car progress cars that are missing parts grouped by model?

I have the below query so far, should I be doing an left outer join?

```
select *
from carprogress cp
    inner join carbuild cb on cp.model = cb.model
```

If someone could explain to me their solution that would be ideal.

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN` . . . or `NOT EXISTS` . . . or `NOT IN`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: If that duplicate doesn't help, there are lots of others that came up in a simple google search.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cb.model, count(*)
from carbuild cb left outer join carprogress cp
on cp.model = cb.model
where cp.model is null
group by cb.model
```