# looking for a function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am new to SQL and I am trying to create a query that will give me the same result as LEFT OUTER JOIN but between two data bases. For example, in DB1 there are 100 records with the value X in specific column and in DB2 there 80 records. I want a query that will give the 20 missing records.
Thanks.

Comment: Databases do not have records in columns.  Databases have schemas.  Schemas have tables.  Tables have columns.

Comment: ok, I phrased it incorrect. I am looking for missing records, meaning the rows in the table that have the value X in column Y.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there any difference between Schemas and Tables?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai A schema contains/defines the tables and other objects and how they relate to each other

Comment: no, there is no difference in terms of "structure". one DB is for Dev environment and the other is for Test environment.

Comment: To query across two databases in Oracle you need a [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5006.htm#SQLRF01205). I am not sure what what kind of function you are looking for though.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "between two tables":

```
select Table1.*
from Table1
left join Table2
on Table1.id = Table2.id
where Table2.id is null
```

This gives everything in Table2 that does not match

For more visual info on joins, go [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

For basic info on SQL, try [here](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_intro.asp)

Comment: @gaishai - if your answer is different to the posted answers please add it as a  response to your own question. Why not contribute to the store of SO wisdom?

Answer (score 0):

```
DB1 (table_users)
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | username  |    lastname  |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 1  | xxxxxx    | mmmmmmm      |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 2  | bbbbbb    | wwwwwww      |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

```
DB2 (table_users)
+----+-----------+--------------+
| id | username  |    lastname  |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 1  | xxxxxx    | mmmmmmm      |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 2  | bbbbbb    |  wwwwwwww    |
+----+-----------+--------------+
| 3  | ccccc     | ppppppppppp  |
+----+-----------+--------------+
```

```
SELECT  *
FROM    DB2.table_users
WHERE   phone_number NOT IN (SELECT * FROM DB2.table_users);
```

I think it servers the same purpose, except that your [dealing with tables from different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another).

Comment: Not in is not a good option in case no records come back, `not in (null) `... Far better to use `where not exists`