# Finding missing number in otherwise Identical Lists

Tags: sql

Suppose we have a list  `A`  and an identical list  `B`  except that  `B`  has one element removed. Find that missing element.

I would think that one possible approach would be the following:

```
 select a.element from
 a left join b
 on a.element = b.element
 where b.element is null
```

Would that be correct?

Comment: That is a fine solution.  Often `not exists` or `not in` would be used.  But this is 100% valid and in some databases has the best performance.

Comment: Other approaches involve `minus` or `except`  `select a.element from A MINUS Select B.element from B` but what you have is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WHERE clause to select a statement where a.element is not present in b.element, like the example below:

```
SELECT a.element
FROM a
WHERE a.element NOT IN (SELECT b.element FROM b)
```

Comment: Please don't just post code here. Explain why this solves the problem.