# mysql left join return records not present in a date range

Tags: mysql, join

I need to find records from table 1 that are not referenced from table2 for a specific date range -- that is, the set of elements from T1 for which there are no references during some date range, in T2.

It seems to me to be a combination of left join of two sub queries.

**Logic**:

Query 1: AllT1Records: return all records from T1

Query 2: AllT1RefsInDateRange: all references to T1 from T2 for a particular date range

Query 3: return those records from AllT1Records that are not present in AllT1RefsInDateRange

**This gets me part of the way there, but returns all records from T1 with no references in T2:**

```
select T1.name, T2.rackName, T2.allocationStart
From T1

LEFT JOIN
T2 on T1.name = T2.rackName

where T2.allocationStart is null
```

**This gets all T1 references for a date range:**

```
select T1.name, T2.rackName, T2.allocationStart from T2, T1

where T2.allocationStart > date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL 60 day)
and T1.name = T2.rackName

group by T1.name
```

What I need is all records from T1 with no references in T2 for a specific date range.  How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems to me to be a combination of left join of two sub queries.

I don't see why you say that.  The first "subquery" you present returns all of table T1, so that's equivalent to T1 itself.  Now, although you *could* form an inline view of some of the records in T2 and form a left join to that, that would be overdoing things a bit.  Me, I would do this:

```
select T1.*
from T1
  left join T2
    on T1.name = T2.rackName
      and T2.allocationStart > date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL 60 day)
where T2.rackName is null
```

That builds on the second query you presented, taking as given your assertion that the criterion on `T2.allocationStart` has the effect you want.  Note that I have incorporated that criterion into the join condition, which is important for achieving the effect you want.  The `where` clause then selects those rows representing T1 rows with no corresponding T2 rows (according to the join condition); we can be sure that no other rows are selected, because if `T2.rackName` is null, then it cannot be that `T2.rackName = T1.name`, not even if `T1.name` is also null.

Comment: I think this is the solution I need! I'm doing some verification and I'll let you know and then mark it "solved"

Answer (score 0):

why are you grouping by t1.name? If there are multiple records for the same t1.name then I would suggest putting the t1 references for a date range in a cte and then use that to do the left join to t2.