# Mysql Join returning duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two tables timetable and subject and i need id,subject_name from subject table which is not used in timetable for specific section.

timetable table
[image: timetable]
subject table

[image: subject]

but it is returning multiple values as you can see in image below.
[image: result]

I am using this query

```
SELECT subject.id, subject.subject_name 
FROM timetable 
LEFT JOIN subject 
ON timetable.subject_id != subject.id AND timetable.class_id = subject.class_id 
WHERE timetable.class_id = 1 and timetable.section_id =1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel yeah i got it..

Comment: please use INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple query worked.

```
SELECT id, subject_name FROM subject WHERE class_id = 1 
AND id NOT IN (SELECT subject_id from timetable where section_id=1)
```

Comment: the `distinct` is not needed

Answer (score 1):

I still think it's a duplicate question. Though your issue is a bit more complex. So try this one:

```
SELECT subject.id, subject.subject_name 
FROM subject
LEFT JOIN timetable 
  ON  timetable.subject_id = subject.id
  AND timetable.class_id   = subject.class_id 
  AND timetable.section_id = 1
WHERE subject.class_id = 1
  AND timetable.id IS NULL
```

Comment: This worked... i also made a query which also works

SELECT id, subject_name FROM subject WHERE class_id = 1 
AND id NOT IN (SELECT subject_id from timetable where section_id=1)