# Query builder - pivot table laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

How do I get only `users` from database where they have no role assigned?
User belongs to many roles, the exact relation is:

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_has_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}
```

My problem is, that I do only work with `Query builder`, not with the model so I do not want to use relation.

EDIT:

I am working with migrations, so please no solutions when using model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `doesntHave`, I believe this uses `QueryBuilder` only.

```
User::doesntHave('roles')->get();
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships

**UPDATE**

Using raw SQL query, you can do this.

Basically what this tries to do is to get all users where its `id` is not found in the `user_has_roles` table (meaning it doesn't have any relations)

```
SELECT  *
FROM    users
WHERE   id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM user_has_roles)
```

I think you can convert this into a *JOIN* or something. I'm not that expert in raw SQL though.

**UPDATE** Trying Query Builder

```
$usersWithoutRoles = DB::table('users')
        ->whereNotIn(function ($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('user_id'))
                  ->from('user_has_roles')
                  ->whereRaw('user_has_roles.user_id = users.id');
        })
        ->get();
```

Reference: [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

You can try other alternatives there.

Comment: Thanks for advice, but I am working with migrations I cannot use model.

Comment: well in that case, you have to create a native query

Comment: I've updated my answer, note that it only *gets*, it doesn't insert (since you didn't include that in your question). And I believe it can be optimized further.

Comment: Oh I forgot about my question, what I really asked for and I posted the whole problem in the answer, sorry about that. Your code, anyways, is what I needed, thanks :)