# How can I make NOT IN clause NULL-safe?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my table structure:

```
// questions_and_answers
+----+-------------------+------+----------+
| id |       body        | type | related  |
+----+-------------------+------+----------+
| 1  | a question        | 0    | NULL     |
| 2  | my answer         | 1    | 1        |
| 3  | another answer    | 1    | 1        |
| 4  | another question  | 0    | NULL     |
| 5  | another answer    | 1    | 4        |
| 6  | another answer    | 1    | 1        |  
+----+-------------------+------+----------+
-- type column: it is either 0 for questions and 1 for answers.
-- related column: it is either null for questions and "the id of its question" for answers
```

Now I need to select all **unanswered** questions. Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM questions_and_answers AS qa
WHERE
  type = 0 -- just questions
  AND
  qa.id NOT IN (SELECT q.related FROM qanda q WHERE q.type <> 0) -- unanswered ones
```

It works well and all fine.

---

**What's my question?** My query matches no row when there is a row like this:

```
| 7  | another answer    | 1    | NULL      |
```

See? the value of `type` is `1`, so it is an answer. But the value of `related` is `NULL`, so it doesn't point to any question. In general that row makes no sense, but probably sometimes happens (when a question is removed and we set the `related` of its answers to `null`). In this case, the result of my query is *"no row selected"*.

Why? And how can I make my query safe against such a situation? *(safe == ignore them and still match unanswered questions)*

Comment: Please leave a comment and explain what's wrong with my question? Why downvote?

Comment: Either switch to NOT EXISTS, or make sure the sub-query returns no null-values.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: And we were doing so well :-(

Comment: @jarlh `NOT EXISTS` throws: `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXISTS (SELECT ...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
where not exists (select 1 from quanda q where q.related = qa.id and q.type <> 0)
```

I strongly recommend that you never use `not in` with a subquery -- specifically because of the `NULL` issue.  Just use `not exists`.  It is also easier to optimize with an index.

Comment: Thank you for both the answer and the tip. Upvote. Just do you know why my question earned lots of downvotes? Just because of lack of a fiddle?

Comment: @MartinAJ . . . I have no idea.  I no longer downvote, and find non-commented downvotes especially rude.

Answer (score 1):

You must only remove all these records (related=NULL) from second SELECT like this

```
SELECT *
FROM qa
WHERE type = 0 -- just questions
  AND id NOT IN 
    (SELECT related 
       FROM qa
       WHERE type <> 0
         AND related IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Comment: The second query is wrong. A static (non-correlated) NOT EXISTS subquery doesn't make sense here.

Comment: yes it is true. I will remove this part from my answer. Thanks!