# Compare two table ids and get results where does not exist in one table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compile a list of "None Sellers", I am getting a list of distinct seller_id's and comparing that to the "list of sellers" aka `account_manager_sellers` using the NOT IN clause, but this is not working for me.

Table `plans`:

```
+----+-----------+
| id | seller_id |
+----+-----------+
|  1 |      1001 |
|  2 |      1002 |
|  3 |      1002 |
|  4 |      1001 |
|  5 |      1005 |
+----+-----------+
```

Table `account_manager_sellers`:

```
+------+--------------+
|  id  | persons_name |
+------+--------------+
| 1001 | name_1       |
| 1002 | name_2       |
| 1003 | name_3       |
| 1004 | name_4       |
| 1005 | name_5       |
+------+--------------+
```

### Expected Result:

```
+------+--------------+
|  id  | persons_name |
+------+--------------+
| 1003 | name_3       |
| 1004 | name_4       |
+------+--------------+


SELECT DISTINCT(p.seller_id) FROM plans p 
WHERE p.seller_id NOT IN (
    SELECT a.id FROM account_manager_sellers a
)
```

This snippet is running but not returning any results.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: Based on the info you provided, the syntax of the query should work.  So this leaves several possibilities -- that account_manager_sellers.id is not the same as seller.id, or that the 2 lists of id's are exactly the same.  You should investigate by running each query independently and looking at them.  I suspect that account_manger_sellers might have a seperate foreign key that is named seller_id possibly.

Comment: `I don't think sample data is required.` well if you know everything then why are you asking here? The query looks ok, so the problem is the data, or you are query the wrong fields

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza updated with sample data.

Comment: btw, `database` is a collection of tables and functions.  Your examples are `Tables`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing things backwards?

**[SQL DEMO:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f41d6/10)**

```
SELECT  a.id, persons_name 
FROM account_manager_sellers a 
WHERE a.id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT p.seller_id FROM plans p
);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
|   id | persons_name |
|------|--------------|
| 1003 |       name_3 |
| 1004 |       name_4 |
```

Comment: After quite a while, this returns:  MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 137.6775 seconds.)

Comment: You need create proper index for your table to improve performance. Provide the create table ddl so we can give you suggestion. Also I create a working demo using your sample data and is returning your desire output. So the problem is your data.

Comment: Ok I have managed to make it work, however, you asked me if I was doing things backwards, maybe yeah, however, think about it like this. The `plans` database will have over 100,000 records, where the `account_manager_sellers` or `a_m_s` for short has only around 5000 records, surely it would be wise to get the DISTINCT values from the `plans` database to compare against the `a_m_s` database?

Comment: Ywa, because that is what you requirement need