# Get values from one table that are not in another

Tags: sql, select, inner-join

The first query works to get a value from t1 that is not in t2.

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.id = '1'
and t1.id2 not in (select t2.id2 from table2 t2 where t2.id='1')
```

But how do how can I do the same thing using this format instead of an inner select?

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.id = '1'
and t2.id = t1.id
and t1.id2 != t2.id2
```

Comment: What does "the same thing using this format" mean? Also this is a faq, all you had to do was google your title. Please read [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
   LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
      ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

`LEFT OUTER JOIN` says to take all results from the LEFT-most table (`table1` here) and only those results from your joined table (`table2` here) that match the `ON` condition. By filtering in your `WHERE` clause to drop any results where `table2.id` IS NULL you effectively only leave `T1` results that are unmatched to `T2`.

Also try to stay away from the `FROM table1, table2` type of implicit join. It's very old school. `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` are better options for nearly any situation.