# Show data that has no data in other tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to show data where data is not in other tables.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code that you used so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This is not a PHP, nor mysqli question. Look at `join`s with `mysql`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a sub query.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tabel_a a
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT b.id FROM tabel_b b)
```

Output

```
id  name
1   aa
2   bb
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d5a32/6/0

Comment: Better is to use `a LEFT JOIN b ... WHERE b.column IS NULL` @A.Colonna   Because `NOT EXISTS` requires a co-related subquery..

Comment: it seems to me If there is no key on id NOT EXISTS is faster