# Get all data from one table that's not in another table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, having-clause

I have a messages table:

```
  mysql> describe messages;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| user1_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| user1     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| user2_id  | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| user2     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| message   | text         | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| timestamp | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| user1read | varchar(3)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| user2read | varchar(3)   | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And then I have a blocked table:

```
 mysql> describe blocked;
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| user_id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| blocked_user_id | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I am trying to do is get all of the data to display in separate divs on a page. This script is called every second. The query I ended up with yielded all messages, no matter the blocked status.

So, let's say my ID is 1, and a blocked user's ID is 5, user 5 should not show up in the list. The same would go for the other user if they logged in.

After messing with that query a while, I attempted a 2nd query. That was even worse because **nothing** appeared on the page, despite data being returned with manual SQL entries using the same query.

The file is rather small, so I will just post the entire thing:

**Edit:** The first query is actually displaying all messages, including myself as a message, which is obviously wrong. It appears my queries are more broken than I thought.

```
 <?php
session_start();

include '../../../config/DB.php';

$username = $_SESSION['logged_in']; //to use in queries

try {
    $db = new DB(); //new DB object
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
}

try {
    $names = array(); //to store during foreach iterations

    //get the id for the other query attempt
    $id_result = $db->getRow('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=?', [$username]);
    $id = $id_result['id'];

    foreach ($messages_result = $db->getRows('SELECT messages.user1, messages.user2, messages.timestamp, messages.message, messages.user2read, users.avatar
                                                    FROM messages
                                                    LEFT JOIN users ON messages.user1 = users.username
                                                    WHERE messages.user2 = ? AND 
                                                    (users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM blocked))
                                                    OR (users.id NOT IN (SELECT blocked_user_id FROM blocked))
                                                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC', [$username]) as $result) {
        $sender = $result['user1'];
        $time = $result['timestamp'];
        $message = $result['message'];
        $avatar = $result['avatar'];
        $user2read = $result['user2read'];

        //Do this so users will only show once.
        //One div per user, and when clicked
        //all messages are shown elsewhere on a page.
        if (!in_array($sender, $names)) {
            $names[] = $sender;

            //If the message is unread, show name in bold
            //Else show regular text
            //$avatar has been removed from the html for now
            //It shows up in an <img> tag
            if ($user2read === 'no') {
                echo '<div id="single_message" data-sender="' . $sender . '"><p style="padding-left:8px;"><p><a class="link" style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;" href=' . $sender . '>' . $sender . '</a></strong></p><p style="white-space:pre-wrap;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;">' . $message . '</p><p style="padding-left:8px;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">' . $time . '</p></div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div id="single_message" data-sender="' . $sender . '"><p style="padding-left:8px;"><p><a class="link" href=' . $sender . '>' . $sender . '</a></p><p style="white-space:pre-wrap;margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;">' . $message . '</p><p style="padding-left:8px;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">' . $time . '</p></div>';
            }

        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

Here is the 2nd query I tried (I'll just show the foreach). This is the one that shows nothing on the page.

```
 foreach($messages_result = $db->getRows('SELECT * FROM messages m LEFT JOIN blocked b ON ((m.user1_id = b.user_id OR m.user2_id = b.user_id)
                                                    AND (m.user1_id = b.blocked_user_id OR m.user2_id = b.blocked_user_id))
                                                    WHERE (m.user1_id = 1 OR m.user2_id = 1) HAVING m.user_id IS NULL
                                                    ORDER BY timestamp DESC', [$id]) as $result) {
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. PS x [NOT] IN (..., y, ...) is NULL when x or y are NULL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: The problem with that question is they only needed to compare one column. I have multiple columns to compare (user1_id and user2_id in messages and user_id and blocked_user_id in blocked).

Comment: The duplicate's join is on one condtion; yours is on another. Then the null-extended rows from the left join are kept. You only want some of those. But if you don't see that then there are a zillion other duplicates.

Comment: I need all messages where user1_id is neither user_id or blocked_user_id in the blocked table, as well as user2_id not being user_id or blocked_user_id in blocked table. I'm really not following you. The 'duplicate' needed all calls from people not in the phone book. So yes, that's one condition. However, I have to match more than 1 condition. user1_id != user_id or blocked_user_id, and user2_id != user_id or blocked_user_id.

Comment: The applications that your question & the duplicate address & the details of conditions don't matter & are not why the post is a duplicate. What matters is finding rows that do not match rows in another table, and that is an easily found faq. Standard SQL has EXCEPT but there are idioms using LEFT JOIN & using NOT IN. Although one has to understand how those work. I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar script that gets all users from the users table that are not blocked, versus getting data from the messages table. Since this compared only the user id with the blocked ids, I was able to do it with one query block. However, I needed to check all possibilities between user1_id and user2_id from messages, and user_id and blocked_user_id from blocked. This required an additional block which was a reversed version of the first block.

I will show how this was successful by showing the id and username from users, then everyone from the blocked table, then the results using ids that are in the blocked table.

```
mysql> select id, username from users;
+----+-----------------+
| id | username        |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | csheridan       |
|  2 | testuser        |
|  3 | testuser2       |
|  4 | washington_user |
+----+-----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from blocked;
+---------+-----------------+
| user_id | blocked_user_id |
+---------+-----------------+
|       1 |               2 |
|       1 |               4 |
+---------+-----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT m.* FROM messages m   
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blocked b 
       WHERE b.user_id = m.user1_id AND b.blocked_user_id = 1) 
       AND NOT EXISTS 
       (SELECT 1 FROM blocked b WHERE b.blocked_user_id = m.user1_id AND b.user_id = 1)   
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blocked b WHERE b.user_id = m.user2_id AND b.blocked_user_id = 1) 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blocked b WHERE b.blocked_user_id = m.user2_id AND b.user_id = 1) 
       ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
+----+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | user1_id | user1     | user2_id | user2     | message        | timestamp           | user1read | user2read |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
|  2 |        3 | testuser2 |        1 | csheridan | Hey!           | 2018-11-14 12:12:35 | yes       | no        |
|  4 |        3 | testuser2 |        1 | csheridan | Are you there? | 2018-11-14 12:12:35 | yes       | no        |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT m.* FROM messages m   
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blocked b  
       WHERE b.user_id = m.user1_id AND b.blocked_user_id = 2) 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blocked b WHERE b.blocked_user_id = m.user1_id AND b.user_id = 2)   
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blocked b WHERE b.user_id = m.user2_id AND b.blocked_user_id = 2) 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM blocked b WHERE b.blocked_user_id = m.user2_id AND b.user_id = 2) 
       ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
+----+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | user1_id | user1           | user2_id | user2    | message             | timestamp           | user1read | user2read |
+----+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
|  7 |        4 | washington_user |        2 | testuser | Hey man! What's up? | 2018-11-14 14:32:27 | yes       | no        |
|  8 |        4 | washington_user |        2 | testuser | Hello there.        | 2018-11-14 14:32:27 | yes       | no        |
+----+----------+-----------------+----------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So, the problem was that I was on the right track, I just needed another block. First, I checked on blocked.user_id = messages.user1_id AND blocked.user_id = ?, then I checked the **other** condition for user2_id. Unless someone comes up with a more compact query, this is what I needed. 
If I only did the first block, it did not check all conditions and still returned blocked users since it didn't check both user1_id and user2_id from messages.

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE (m.user1_id = 1 OR m.user2_id = 1) HAVING m.user_id IS NULL` i think its contradicting each other bcos you have this on join `ON ((m.user1_id = b.user_id OR m.user2_id = b.user_id) AND (m.user1_id = b.blocked_user_id OR m.user2_id = b.blocked_user_id))`....its like canceling each other........

Rectify this....maybe can....good luck

Comment: I'm needing both possibilities since both users could be user1 or user2. They are formatted later on the web page. When a message is sent, the user is always user1 from their point of view. But they are user2 on the other person's.

Answer (score 0):

A left join on blocked users with matching of `user2` ("me") to `blocked.user_id`, the person who blocks, and `user1` against `blocked.blocked_user_id` the user who is blocked, if the result is NULL (aka b.user_id IS NULL), then there is no block.

```
foreach($messages_result = $db->getRows('
SELECT messages.user1, messages.user2, messages.timestamp, messages.message, messages.user2read, users.avatar
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN users ON messages.user1 = users.username
LEFT JOIN blocked b ON b.user_id = messages.user2_id AND b.blocked_user_id = messages.user1_id
WHERE messages.user2 = ? AND b.user_id IS NULL
ORDER BY timestamp DESC',[$username]) as $result) {
...
```

Comment: That's what I'm needing, users that are not blocked, which would show up as NULL in the blocked table.

Comment: For clarity, you don't need to do anything in the blocked table. The `LEFT JOIN` will create all NULL results within the query if there is no matching `ON` criteria. Please mark answer correct/upvote if useful for you.

Comment: This led me on the right track, accept for one minor detail. By using `IS NULL`, it showed only the users that are blocked, or that blocked me, which was the opposite of the goal. I changed it to `IS NOT NULL` and it worked both manually in mysql terminal and on the front end. Thank you so much for your help. I'll accept, but add that edit if you don't mind.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the direction of the blocking and I don't think the edit is right either. user2 is the current username, therefore user1 needs to match against blocked_user_id.

Comment: Update: I'm still having trouble. I signed in as another user and now it's only showing one user that is not blocked. It still helped though.