# I need the records which doesn't matches in both tables

Tags: mysql, join

I need those records in a table list which doesn't link to table t1 to table t2

I have tried inner join. I need the records without subquery

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE t2 LIKE t1;

INSERT INTO t1(id) VALUES(1),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO t2(id) VALUES(2),(3),(4);
```

---

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> select * from t2;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
+----+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

I need :

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  4 |
+----+
```

Comment: (Obviously--) This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. When you ask a question show what you have tried & researched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 0):

`select * from t1 where not exists (select * from t2 where t1.id = t2.id)`

or

`select * from t1 where id not in (select id from t2)`

and likewise for t2. Union them together if you want them in a single result set.

Update: subquery-less version:

```
select coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) from t1 full outer join t2 on (t1.id = t2.id)
where t1.id is null or t2.id is null
```

Comment: Thanks.
Comment for the First query: But I don't want to use a subquery.
Comment for the Second query: There is a limit of in a conditional statement.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. I added a solution that doesn't use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

you could try left join on the union of the id and check for null

```
select  t3.id  
from  (
  select  t1.id from t1 
  union 
  select t2.id  from t2 
) t3 
left join t1 on t1.id  = t3.id 
left join t2. on t2.id  = t3.id 
where t2.id is null  
or t1.id is null
```

Comment: You have created a temp table using a subquery. Please solve without subquery.
What if there were 1 lakh each table records then.

Comment: @Er.SujeetKumar   SO is not a fre coding service  .. but a question/answer  site  .. based on your question my answer is a right solution  ..  .. you don't want  a subuery .. then  you should find a method for obtain  all the id fro b9th the table and join with the table itself  .. i think  that a union  is thye simplest way