# Anti Join based on multiple keys / columns (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join

The setting is simple, I wanted to retrieve all rows from `table A` that were not present in `table B`. Because a unique row can be identified using 4 columns, I needed to have a way to write the `WHERE` statement that it works correctly.

My solution is to concatenate the 4 columns and use that as "one" column/key to do the outer join:

```
select      * 
from        table_A
where       filter_condition = 0
and         (column1 || column2 || column3 || column4) not in (
            select          A.column1 || A.column2 || A.column3 || A.column4
            from            table_A A -- 1618727
            inner join      table_B B
            on              A.column1 = B.column1 
            and             A.column2 = B.column2 
            and             A.column3 = B.column3 
            and             A.column4 = B.column4
            and             filter_condition = 0
            )
```

My question is, is this a good way of doing this or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

To be clear, the desired result is simply to get back only the rows of table_A that I "lose" due to the `INNER JOIN` with table_A and table_B.

Comment: Which table does the column filter_condition belong to?

Comment: Any null values involved?

Comment: Note that `'AB' || 'C' = 'A' || 'BC'`, but `('AB', 'C') <> ('A', 'BC')`.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is a duplicate, why did you reopen it? The asker in the post: 'To be clear, the desired result is simply to get back only the rows of table_A that I "lose" due to the INNER JOIN with table_A and table_B.' The asker in a comment: 'Marked my question as duplicate, sorry for the inconvenience.' (From revisions: 'Post Closed as "duplicate" by philipxy, jarlh, Community♦')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `not exists`:

```
select a.* 
from table_a a
where a.filter_condition = 0
and not exists (
    select 1
    from table_b b
    where 
        a.column1 = b.column1 
        and a.column2 = b.column2 
        and a.column3 = b.column3 
        and a.column4 = b.column4
)
```

This will give you all records in `table_a` that do not have a corresponding record in `table_b`.

Comment: This seems the safest and best solution, as it returns the two rows I am looking for (and not a lot of others as well).  Marked my question as duplicate, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` between `A` and `B` and checking for a `NULL` row in `B` is probably easier:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_A A
LEFT JOIN table_B B ON A.column1 = B.column1 
                   AND A.column2 = B.column2 
                   AND A.column3 = B.column3 
                   AND A.column4 = B.column4
WHERE B.column1 IS NULL
  AND A.filter_condition = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use tuples (aka row constructors) in PostgreSQL:

```
select * 
from table_a
where filter_condition = 0
and (column1, column2, column3, column4) not in
(
  select column1, column2, column3, column4
  from table_b
);
```

If the columns can be null, then better use `NOT EXISTS`, as null=null results in "unknown" rather than in true or false.

Comment: The tuple comparison properly deals with null values: https://rextester.com/XDWI48444

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Ah, great. Thank you for checking this. So, this would only be a problem when *all* these columns were null in a table_b row.

Comment: Correct, in that case we are back to the old "NOT IN problem" with null values.