# Obtaining only certain values (sql)

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 different tables: **table1, table2, table3**

> **Table 1** contains all the different orders that were purchased
>
> **Table 2** contains the detail of every order (i mean, it contains a
>   column called **ORDER_DETAIL** and the number represent an item of
>   that order -a unique value)
>
> **Table 3** contains the workflow.. some numbers that were inside 
>   ORDER_DETAIL from Table 2 will appear here because this item must be
>   approved to be delivered

**I want to obtain all the different orders whose items did not appear in Table 3.**

This picture explains everything:

[image]

This is my SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bfc22/2

I did this query but i am not getting what i want:

```
select * from table1 kio
inner join table2 jio on kio.ORDER_NUMBER = jio.ORDER_NUMBER
where jio.CANCELLED = 0
and not exists (select 1 from table3 gio where jio.ORDER_DETAIL = gio.ORDER_DETAIL)
```

Also, how can i obtain those orders whose ORDER_DETAILs only appear on TABLE 2 **AND** those orders whose order_details appear in table 3 with PROCESSED = 1 and APPROVED = 1? All in the same query.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please put all your question in your post, not just at a fiddle. Please ask 1 question per post.  When you get a result that you don't expect/understand, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first unexpected/misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) For errors a [mre] includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation: join `table1` with `table2`, then left join `table3`, aggregate by `order_number` and filter on groups that have no match in `table3`.

```
select t1.id, t1.order_number
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t2.order_number = t1.order_number
left join table3 t3 on t3.order_detail = t2.order_detail
group by t1.id, t1.order_number
having count(t3.order_detail) = 0
```

In your DB Fiddle, this produces:

```
id  order_number
3   46646
```

> Also, how can i obtain those orders whose ORDER_DETAILs only appear on TABLE 2 AND those orders whose order_details appear in table 3 with PROCESSED = 1 and APPROVED = 1? All in the same query

For this, you can just add another pair of conditions in the `having` clause:

```
having 
    count(t3.order_detail) = 0
    or (max(t3.processed) = 1 and max(t3.approved) = 1)
```

Yields:

```
id  order_number
1   78945
3   46646
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying!. Why did you use 'or' instead of 'and' in the having condition? Also,is it possible to solve this without using group by?

Comment: @Student_new: I understood that you want orders that either have no records in table3, or that have records with `processed = 1` and `approved = 1`. Both conditions cannot be fulfilled at the same time, hence `or`. Also, `group by` seems to me like the simplest way to handle this, why would not use it?

Comment: Oh, yeah. My bad. Yeah, i was trying to make it a little harder that's why i was thinking about another option. I tried but i was not able to do this without group by condition. Is that even possible?

Comment: @Student_new: to me your requirement is an aggregate query in essence. While it may be possible to do it another way (with a series of subqueries maybe), I think that aggregation is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to obtain all the different orders whose items did not appear in Table 3.

This seems like a reasonable interpretation of the question, although you add more questions later.

If so, then you don't seem to need `table1`:

```
select t2.order_number
from table2 t2 left join
     table3 t3
     on t2.ORDER_DETAIL = t3.ORDER_DETAIL
group by t2.order_number
having count(t3.ORDER_DETAIL) = 0;
```