# Get Ids not exists in another table

Tags: sql-server, join, select, sql-server-2016

I have the following table called TableA

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
| RequestId | FkLId  | FkSId  |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 100       | 285301 | 110    |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 200       | 285301 | 99     |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 300       | 285301 | 100    |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 400       | 285301 | 98     |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 500       | 285301 | 93     |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 600       | 285302 | 93     |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 700       | 285302 | 94     |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

And also have another table called TableB

```
+-----------+--------+-------+
| ServiceId | FkLId  | FkSId |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 500       | 285301 | 109   |
+-----------+--------+-------+
| 501       | 285301 | 99    |
+-----------+--------+-------+
```

I need to take All the Ids in TableA, not exists in TableB. My Query as follows,

```
SELECT FkSId
FROM   TableA 
WHERE  FkLId NOT IN (SELECT FkSId FROM TableB) AND FkLId = 285301
```

But its only returns `110` I need `110,100,98,93` output

Comment: Should you change where clause from WHERE FkLID... to WHERE FkSID?

Comment: Change "where FkLId NOT IN" to "where FkSId NOT IN" .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT FkSId
FROM   TableA 
WHERE  FkSId NOT IN (SELECT FkSId FROM TableB WHERE FkLId = 285301) AND FkLId = 28530
```

Comment: What is the difference of my query and your one?

Comment: @Adam You are searching by `FkLId ` - I am filtering by `FkSid`

Comment: still I had the same issue with your query, So I change it as `SELECT FkSId 
FROM   TableA 
WHERE  FkSId NOT IN (SELECT FkSId FROM TableB where FkLId = 285301) AND FkLId = 285301` and problem solved

Comment: @Adam Yes, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0fec7ab87ceda0668a5ed31fdf933c8f)

The problem is here

```
WHERE FkSId NOT IN (SELECT FkSId FROM TableB where FkLId = 285301)
```

You should change from `FkLId` to `FkSId` like below

```
SELECT FkSId 
FROM TableA 
WHERE FkSId NOT IN (SELECT FkSId FROM TableB where FkLId = 285301) AND FkLId = 285301
```

**Output**

```
FkSId
110
100
98
93
```

Comment: @Adam Did you check my answer? https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: yes, but the problem is still occurred, what I did was I changed the query as follows,
`SELECT FkSId 
FROM   TableA 
WHERE  FkSId NOT IN (SELECT FkSId FROM TableB where FkLId = 285301) AND FkLId = 285301` and problem solved

Comment: I got it, you want to filter in TableB. So check my answer again, please

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `FkLId` to `FkSId`. It will solve your problem.

```
  SELECT FkSId
    FROM   TableA 
    WHERE  FkSId NOT IN (SELECT FkSId FROM TableB) AND FkLId = 285301
```