# Select values which are not present in other table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, left-join

I want to be able to pick peoples in table 1 that did not gave or asked ID#1(jud) for loans.
MY 2 tables.

```
table 1
----------------------
id*|name|adress
1  |jud |pipi #5
2  |john|yoba #45
3  |jan |stackyflow 54
4  |Song|doesnt matter street 98

Table 2
-------------
*id|asked_loan|gave_loan
1  |1         |2
2  |1         |3
```

In this case i will want to get only Table1 row #4 which is :

```
4  |Song|doesnt matter street 98
```

**What i tried :**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `id`,`name`,`adress`
FROM `TABLE1`
LEFT JOIN `TABLE2` ON TABLE1.asked_loan = TABLE1.id
WHERE `asked_loan` !=1 AND `gave_loan` !=1
```

**My problem:**
Since i am left joining, the 2 tables hook together so users not present in TABLE2 will not show up.

**Summary:**
I want to be able to select users that did not gave or receive (TABLE1 id)#1 a loan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: No it does not, i want to check against 1 specific value

Comment: Please give a [mre]. PS In the duplicate the table that has no matching value goes 2nd.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the rows that are not matching:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  TABLE1.id,`name`,`adress` 
    FROM `TABLE1` 
    LEFT JOIN `TABLE2` ON TABLE2.asked_loan=TABLE1.id  
     AND  `asked_loan` !=1 
      AND `gave_loan` !=1
    WHERE  TABLE2.asked_loan is null
```

Comment: I tried this but i get an error,should i add a sign after TABLE2.asked_loan=TABLE1.id  ?

Comment: This works when there is only 1 record of everything but if there is more records it wont work. for example if table 2 has row of (4)(2). it will show up in the results

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using `NOT EXISTS` through

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
      (SELECT 0 
         FROM table2 t2 
        WHERE t1.ID IN (t2.asked_loan,t2.gave_loan) )
```

matching those two columns of `table2` with `ID` column of `table1`

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=746ec5f2f8db15e509c5313985f37a30)</kbd>

Comment: Its a great step but this is not really what i want, this gives the users that never gave or received a loan from nobody. I want to get the users who never gave or took a loan from only ID 4.