# List the firstname, lastname of employees who are Sales Reps who have no assigned customers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

The employeenumber data in the [employeestable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiqmw.png) is similar to the salesrepemployeenumber in the customers table[customers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQnkD.png).

Some employees are not in the customers table.

How do I find the employees who are not in the salesrepemployeenumber row but presnt as employeenumber in the employees table .

note the data in the two rows is the same . and right and left join are not working

this is my code

```
select e.firstname, e.lastname, e.employeeNumber
from employees e 
    right join customers c on e.employeeNumber=c.salesRepEmployeeNumber 
where c.salesrepemployeeNumber is null
```

Comment: What is your query returning?  IE: what data is there that should not be there, and/or what data is *not* there that *should* be?

Comment: "and right and left join are not working" - Prove it by providing sample data and expected result. This has been asked many times.. See: [sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/sql-find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: I am getting 22 rows of null columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need employees which are not in  customers table as salesRep. How about the following?

```
select e.firstname, e.lastname, e.employeeNumber
from employees e 
where e.employeeNumber not in (select c.salesRepEmployeeNumber from customers c)
```

Comment: it worked, the problem was I was not looking at employees who were not sales reps like managers

Answer (score 1):

Try using left join

```
select e.firstname, e.lastname, e.employeeNumber
from employees e 
LEFT join customers c on e.employeeNumber=c.salesRepEmployeeNumber 
where c.salesrepemployeeNumber is null
```

Comment: what do you mean with  "not working"  ...  you have an error ?? show the exact error message ...  wrong result  ?? .. add  a  proper data sample  .. the expected result and your actual result  ..

Comment: @lak . . . This is a correct answer to your question.  If it doesn't work for you, then either you did not ask the question you intend or there is operator error.