# Only show Warehous where product is not existing - multiply tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got three tables. Product, Warehouse and IsIn.

Product:

- productID
- name
- price

Warehouse:

- warehousID
- name

IsIn:

- productID*
- warehousID*
- quantity

I now want to write a question where i get all warehouses where a specific product does not exist.

I can get a table where the specific product are, but when i try to get where it's not, I get the wrong answer.

Does anyone know how i can write the question?

Comment: So exactly what was your attempt? Edit question to show.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I now want to write a question where i get all warehouses where a specific product does not exist.

This sounds like a `NOT EXISTS` query:

```
select w.*
from warehouse w
where not exists (select 1
                  from isin i
                  where i.warehouseid = w.warehouseid and
                        i.productid = ?
                 );
```

You may want to add `and i.quantity > 0` in the subquery.  It is not clear if quantity is important for the question.