# Nested join, no value in one of the tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 4 tables
Tab1 -- columns: id
Tab2 -- columns: id, Tab1Id
Tab3 -- columns: id, Tab2Id
Tab4 -- columns: id, Tab3Id

There could be multiple rows of same id from another table. Eg: same Tab1Id can be present multiple times in Tab2, same Tab3Id can be present in Tab4 multiple times etc

I want to now get all Tab1 records, that dont have any rows in Tab4 through the connected tables.

I am able to get all the Tab3 that done have entry in Tab4, but then how do I put them in a group to know what entries from Tab1 have no entries in Tab4.

```
Tab1
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+

Tab2
+----+--------+
| id | Tab1Id |
+----+--------+
| 10 | 1      |
+----+--------+
| 20 | 1      |
+----+--------+
| 30 | 2      |
+----+--------+
| 40 | 2      |
+----+--------+

Tab3
+----+--------+
| id | Tab2Id |
+----+--------+
| 100 | 10    |
+----+--------+
| 200 | 10    |
+----+--------+
| 300 | 20    |
+----+--------+

Tab4
+------+--------+
| id | Tab3Id |
+------+--------+
| 1000 | 100    |
```

So with my query I only want the id 2 from Tab1, as none of the corresponding entries for this id exist in Tab4

Comment: [SQL - find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/q/367863/3404097) etc etc

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM Tab1 t1 
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT t2.Tab1Id 
                  FROM Tab2 t2 
                  INNER JOIN Tab3 t3 on t3.Tab2Id=t2.id 
                  INNER JOIN Tab4 t4 on t4.Tab3Id=t3.id
                  );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=189d2e246b781f28e18dc5f93e847e20

The subquery will return the matching values in Tab2 ,Tab3  and  Tab4  tables which will be filtered out by the `NOT IN` claues.

Another option would be using NOT EXISTS.

```
SELECT t1.id 
FROM Tab1 t1 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1  
                  FROM Tab2 t2 
                  INNER JOIN Tab3 t3 on t3.Tab2Id=t2.id 
                  INNER JOIN Tab4 t4 on t4.Tab3Id=t3.id
                  WHERE t2.Tab1Id=t1.id
                  )
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cde22a13c12c2c32f4860324ae0c92d

Comment: Thank you. But this doesnt solve my purpose as it shows all the records from Tab3 that dont have a record in Tab4. One record in Tab1 could have multiple records. Even if one of them have a record in Tab4, I dont want to show them in results. I have updated my question to have more clarity

Comment: @KayS just changed  `t2.id` with `t2.Tab1Id` and it gives your desired result, check the updated answer