# Rails/SQL - How to find users who does not have premium subscription with joins

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord

I have two models `User` and `Subscription` as follows

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions
end

class Subscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  
  # attributes
  # name string
  # premium boolean
  # ...
end
```

Users will be having many subscription. How Can I find all the users who does not have a premium subscription (premium =true)

`User.where('id not in (select user_id from subscriptions where premium = true)')`. This works for me with subquery. Is there a better way of doing the same with joins?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find records from one table which don't exist in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367863/find-records-from-one-table-which-dont-exist-in-another)

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

You're better using the query you currently have.

Take a look at two other different ways to achieve what you need, their execution time is slightly different (there are many other ways to get this done, but I got no time);

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM subscriptions WHERE premium = TRUE);
                                                    QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on users  (cost=19.79..41.91 rows=485 width=56) (actual time=0.025..0.032 rows=2 loops=1)
   Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Seq Scan on subscriptions  (cost=0.00..18.70 rows=435 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)
           Filter: premium
           Rows Removed by Filter: 2
 Planning Time: 0.051 ms
 Execution Time: 0.053 ms
(9 rows)

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN subscriptions ON subscriptions.premium = TRUE AND subscriptions.user_id = users.id WHERE subscriptions.id IS NULL;
                                                   QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Right Join  (cost=31.83..51.67 rows=5 width=56) (actual time=0.045..0.055 rows=2 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (subscriptions.user_id = users.id)
   Filter: (subscriptions.id IS NULL)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2
   ->  Seq Scan on subscriptions  (cost=0.00..18.70 rows=435 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)
         Filter: premium
         Rows Removed by Filter: 2
   ->  Hash  (cost=19.70..19.70 rows=970 width=56) (actual time=0.021..0.024 rows=4 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
         ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..19.70 rows=970 width=56) (actual time=0.007..0.013 rows=4 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.081 ms
 Execution Time: 0.077 ms
(12 rows)

EXPLAIN ANALYZE WITH f AS (SELECT user_id FROM subscriptions WHERE premium = TRUE) SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM f);
                                                    QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on users  (cost=19.79..41.91 rows=485 width=56) (actual time=0.023..0.029 rows=2 loops=1)
   Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 2
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Seq Scan on subscriptions  (cost=0.00..18.70 rows=435 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.008 rows=2 loops=1)
           Filter: premium
           Rows Removed by Filter: 2
 Planning Time: 0.062 ms
 Execution Time: 0.050 ms
(9 rows)
```

Comment: Looks like first and last are the same for RDBMS. If you are interested, you can see my comparison with `EXISTS`

Answer (score -1):

As @The russian shame said your query perfomance is good enough

I just add another query with `EXISTS` to compare

You can use [`where_exists`](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem for this purpose as

```
User.where_not_exists(:subscriptions, premium: true)
```

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM users WHERE (NOT (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM subscriptions WHERE (subscriptions.user_id = users.id) AND premium = TRUE)));
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Anti Join  (cost=123.50..153.00 rows=9 width=24) (actual time=2.652..3.357 rows=91 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (users.id = subscriptions.user_id)
   ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..17.00 rows=1000 width=24) (actual time=0.020..0.264 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=92.00..92.00 rows=2520 width=8) (actual time=2.617..2.618 rows=2520 loops=1)
         Buckets: 4096  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 131kB
         ->  Seq Scan on subscriptions  (cost=0.00..92.00 rows=2520 width=8) (actual time=0.013..1.653 rows=2520 loops=1)
               Filter: premium
               Rows Removed by Filter: 2480
 Planning Time: 0.504 ms
 Execution Time: 3.409 ms
(10 rows)
```

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM subscriptions WHERE premium = TRUE);
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on users  (cost=98.30..117.80 rows=500 width=24) (actual time=0.722..0.878 rows=91 loops=1)
   Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 909
   SubPlan 1
     ->  Seq Scan on subscriptions  (cost=0.00..92.00 rows=2520 width=8) (actual time=0.004..0.415 rows=2520 loops=1)
           Filter: premium
           Rows Removed by Filter: 2480
 Planning Time: 0.055 ms
 Execution Time: 0.899 ms
(9 rows)
```

Comment: this will not help since there can be multiple subscriptions for a single user with and without premiums.